# RegEx to match phrase with uppercase words at beginning and ending

Tags: regex

"UPPERCASEWORD UPPERCASEWORD lowercaseword UPPERCASEWORD UPPERCASEWORD"

The following RegEx matches the above pattern well but fails to match if there a digit in the middle. 
\b[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]+(?:[\sa-z,]+[A-Z]+)*\b

"UPPERCASEWORD UPPERCASEWORD lowercaseword 1(or any digit) UPPERCASEWORD UPPERCASEWORD" will not match

Any idea how to include a numeral in the match? I tried some options with [0-9] in between but did not work.

Comment: `[A-Z]+\s+[A-Z]+\s+[a-z]+\s*[0-9]*\s*[A-Z]+\s+[A-Z]+`

Comment: @pogo, I don't think the author wants spaces in there, otherwise their existing pattern wouldn't be working when there is no digit. Admittedly, it's not very clear. Sample data helps enormously in questions like this.

Comment: Which language or tool are you using for this?

Comment: I am using TRegEx in Delphi but also trying it with EditPad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the given pattern appears to match:

1. 3 or more upper case characters, then
2. 1 or more lower case characters (or commas or spaces), then
3. 1 or more upper case characters

You might want this pattern:

```
\b[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]+(?:[\sa-z,]+[0-9]*[A-Z]+)*\b
```

which is equivalent to:

```
\b[A-Z]{3,}(?:[\sa-z,]+[0-9]*[A-Z]+)*\b
```

Or, if you want to allow just 2 (or potentially more) upper case characters before the lowercase one, then this:

```
\b[A-Z]{2,}(?:[\sa-z,]+[0-9]*[A-Z]+)*\b
```

It would help if you posted some test data.

Update: It sounds like you want something quite different to what you originally described. Will this do, or does it match too much?

```
\b[A-Z]{2}.*[A-Z]{2}\b
```

If that matches too much, then if your tool supports negative lookahead then this might work, but it's getting pretty messy:

```
\b[A-Z]{2}((?!\b[a-z][a-z'0-9]+\b\s[a-z][a-z'0-9]+).)*[A-Z]{2}\b
```

Comment: Thanks! but the above formulas still skip the number I have a better data here: "the best days and time to reach us are MONDAY AFTER 1 PM, TUESDAY after 3 O'CLOCK, and WEDNESDAY while all other days, we're not available". I need a formula to match everything and including MONDAY to WEDNSDAY.

Comment: You are absolutely God send! Man very understandable and works like a charm!! Thanks again!!